# Python - to_dict('records') creating a list type need a dictionary to access values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am extracting a random row from a df and then attempting to create a dictionary with each column being a key, and the values from the column to be the matching value in the dict. When I use to_dict('records'), however, it is actually generating a list within python.  How can I create the dictionary, so I can access the values?  My intent is to actually create a list from the values that I can feed into a knapsack optimization function that I can then match back to the keys afterward.  Any recommendations?

[Sample Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1yOH.png)

```
    sample = random_lets_df.sample() 
    rand_dict = sample.to_dict('records')
    type(rand_dict)
```

Output

```
  list
```

```
    rand_dict_val = list(rand_dict.values())
```

Output

```
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

rand_dict provides the following output, but the type is still a list and not a dictionary

```
[{'a': 367.13144360806575,
  'b': 431.8344058766508,
  'c': 896.1165310569901,
  'd': 265.8757724175083,
  'e': 180.2252614234264,
  'f': 1631.5502218183503}]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to improve your question so we can help you. And please, don't insert image of code, instead, write to code to show how we can create a small `random_lets_df` to help you.

Comment: Output of `to_dict('records')` is a dictionaries, one for each row.

Comment: Someone responded with a solution, but it appears they deleted their answer, which actually works.  Adding [0] corrected the issue: rand_dict = sample.to_dict('records')[0]

Answer (score 0):

From https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

When you add the 'records' to_dict returns a list of dictionnaries: so you should use `to_dict` without parameters.

```
sample = random_lets_df.sample() 
rand_dict = sample.to_dict()
type(rand_dict)
```

Comment: That will create a dictionary, but the key will then be the index #. Records is what removes the index from the dictionary.

Comment: Oh yes you right, then just grab the first element from the list if you only need one element with `rand_dict[0]` ?